# How to display 2 function calls in same line?

Tags: functions

```
<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
<?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>
```

When I call above 2 functions you will see the output in two lines.

But what Need is "Andrew 2.10"

I need both output in same line. How to do it.

Comment: There's no reason those 2 items shouldn't be on the same line, can we see the surrounding code/markup? Can I ask why you've doubled the number of PHP tags? The ?> <?php between your 2 function calls is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Put the two functions on same line, like this:

```
<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>
```

If this doesn't work, first get the values and then output them, like this:

```
<?php
    $author_name = get_author();
    $author_link = get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) );
    $post_time   = get_the_time('g:i a');
?>
<p>
    <a href="<?php echo $author_link; ?>" title="<?php echo $author_name; ?>"><?php echo $author_name; ?></a> <?php echo $post_time; ?>
</p>
```